# Return a variable after an axios.post() request

Tags: javascript, axios, frontend

I'm pretty new to front end and programming in general.
This my code snippet:

```
addPerson() {
  //this.addInventory()

  let url = "http://localhost:8080/savefood/persons";
  axios.post(url, this.person).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    
    this.updateInventory(response.data.idPerson, this.addInventory())});

  // reset input fields
  this.person = {};
},
addInventory() {
  let url = "http://localhost:8080/savefood/inventories";
  axios.post(url, this.inventory).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data)});

  // reset input fields
  this.inventory = {};
},
```

What I'm trying to do is to return from `addInventory()`an `idInventory` which will be created with the `axios.post()`.I'm failing at all my attempts. Is there a way to extract the `idInventory` from the response and then return it? My goal is to return the `idInventory` from `addInventory()`so that `updateInventory(...)` is able to work properly. If I simply replace `this.addInventory()` in `updateInventory(..)` with an id of an existing inventory it will work fine. But I want to be able to create an inventory and a person and then attach the just created inventory to the person. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `addInventory` function needs to return a `Promise` which you will resolve inside `addPerson` to get `idInventory`.

Comment: If you don't mind using [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) you could do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/c45b95c9fc48ddede559f1cabc5c863a).